# Java Program to calculate a robo facing direction and its co ordinates value

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 5*5 matrix and initally the robo is at co ordinates (2,2) facing north.
Robo moves in the direction Left,Right,Up,Down,Left.
I have to Calculate the co ordinates of the robo after the movement(LRUDL) and its final facing direction.

Below is the code i have tried, but i am not able to get the robo direction in it.
It would be great if someone could help me on this

enter code here

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FinalPosition {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        System.out.println("Enter the moving direction:");
        String move = br1.readLine();
        //String move = "LRUDL"; 
        position(move); 

    }

    private static void position(String move) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        System.out.println("Enter the X axis co ordinates:");
        int xaxis = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the Y axis co ordinates:");
        int yaxis = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the initial direction of the robot");
        String direction = br.readLine(); 

        int l = move.length();
        int countUp = 0, countDown = 0; 
        int countLeft = 0, countRight = 0; 
        int x =0;
        int y= 0;
        int count= 0;

        char [] c=move.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(c);

        for(int i=0; i< c.length; i++) {

            if(c[i]== 'U')
                countUp++; 
            else if (c[i] == 'D') 
                countDown++; 
            else if (c[i] == 'L') 
                countLeft++; 
            else if (c[i] == 'R') 
                countRight++; 
            else 
                count = 0;
        }

        if(countRight >= countLeft){
             x = (countRight - countLeft);
        } else {
             x = (countLeft - countRight);
        }

        if(countUp >= countDown ){
            y = (countUp - countDown);
        } else {
            y = (countDown - countUp);
        } 

        System.out.println("X AXIS IS"+   x   + "  Y AXIS IS  "+ y);
        System.out.println("xaxis "+ xaxis   + "  yaxis  "+ yaxis);
        int finalXaxisPosition = xaxis - x;
        int finalYaxisPosition = yaxis - y;
        System.out.println("Final Position: "+ finalXaxisPosition + "," + finalYaxisPosition);
    }

}
```

Comment: What inputs did you use, what output did it give you, and what output should it have given you?

Comment: I entered "LRUDL" with 2,2 and it resulted in 1,2 which seems correct to me. I'm not sure what you're having a problem with.

Comment: i want to get the final direction of the robot after the movement of LRUDL

Comment: Input:

Enter the moving direction:
LRUDL
Enter the X axis co ordinates:
2
Enter the Y axis co ordinates:
2  

Output:
Final Position: 1,2

Initially the robo was facing North , after the movement of (LRUDL) i want to get its facing direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be overthinking this.

The final direction you face is simply the final move you make. No matter what moves you make, if your final move is left, your robot is always facing West, for example.

```
String direction = "";
int lastIndex = move.length - 1;
switch(c[lastIndex]) {
    case 'L': direction = "West"; break;
    case 'U': direction = "North"; break;
    case 'D': direction = "South"; break;
    case 'R': direction = "East"; break;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot accept movement " + c[lastIndex]);
}
System.out.println("Final Direction: " + direction);
```